# How to take rectangular screenshot in C# without using System.Drawing?

Tags: c#, screenshot

It seems that nowadays using `System.Drawing` is discouraged for new projects. As a replacement, even Microsoft themselves recommend moving to libaries like ImageSharp or SkiaSharp (or WIC - though AFAICT, that would require interop to COM).

However, I have not yet found an equivalent to `Graphics.CopyFromScreen()` in the docs of any of those libraries... How would you accomplish that task in a "proper" state-of-the-art .NET 5/6 application nowadays?

To clarify "that task": Take a screenshot of a rectangular area of my screen (typically a window) and save it to an image file with given encoding parameters (i.e. format, quality, scaling, etc.). Being able to also embed EXIF metadata would be a bonus.

---

Alternatively, how "bad" would it really be to keep using `System.Drawing` if the application in question will most likely remain Windows-only? Also, what would be the most light-weight way of doing this in a .NET 5/6 app? Using the Nuget package Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility does not "feel" particularly "clean"...

Comment: I've never heard of SkiaSharp but a few minutes searching led me to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/SkiaSharp.SKSurface.Snapshot?view=skiasharp-2.80.2) method, which seems like it could be what you need. I'm not sure how to get the `SKSurface` in the first place but that might be something to look into.

Comment: MS is slowly killing off the best features of WinForms since 2008 first via the push for WPF and then with Core. So sad.

Comment: So you have an application that you accept will be windows only but you think using the Windows Compatibility Pack, the nuget package designed for gaining access to Windows only APIs isn't clean? I'm not sure what you're looking for/thinking of that would be cleaner.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: That is a very fair point indeed. Maybe it's because I'm not a native speaker. For some reason my gut reaction to the "Compatibility" moniker was to interpret it as meaning "legacy"...

Comment: ... Also, most articles talking about that package justify its existence primarily with the need to port existing code to .NET Core... which makes it sound like there was a different(/better) way to do the things it does if you were starting from scratch...

Comment: If you target Windows only, 
using System.Drawing is not discouraged.

Comment: @Ray: OK, that's fine with me and I will go with that then. But is it actually *impossible* to take screenshots on Windows without using `System.Drawing` / GDI?

Comment: @OliverGiesen Maybe getting DWM to hand over the handle to a window texture you then read from. Or using the Windows 10+ Game DVR functionality. Both won't work without hardware acceleration / enabled DWM / on remote desktop / proper permissions, and the API may not even be intended for you to use, but you may want to research that, I've never tried it. Obviously setup and interaction with them will be a lot more elaborate. Otherwise GDI itself seems to be a safe choice, just don't expect it to be realtime.